# How to collect textbox value as a Capitalize form in session value

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" name="name" style="text-transform:capitalize">
```

This is my PHP CODE

```
$nameField = $_POST['name'];
<p style=font-size:13px;text-transform:capitalize"> hi $nameField , </p>
```

Whenever i am trying to write anything in textbox its showing "xyz" as "Xyz"

But in sesseion value its showing as "Hi xyz" instead of "Hi Xyz"

Comment: use ucfirst() function. This will transform first character to upper case.

Comment: Its working for me, still you can try like this `ucwords($nameField)`

Comment: @VijayaSankarN thank you sir, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you wrote, the text will appear as `Hi Xyz,` because of the style rule `text-transform:capitalize` that you have on your `<p>` element. It won't get recorded in your variable unless you add the `ucfirst();` function like this:

`$nameField = ucfirst($_POST['name']);`

Answer (score 0):

You could just ucfirst() function.

```
$nameField = ucfirst($_POST['name']);
<p style=font-size:13px;text-transform:capitalize"> hi $nameField , </p>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php